# MySQL pushes CPU to 100% when including subquery in query

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance for your help.

My server suddenly went to 100% CPU usage. After turning off all scripts and gradually reinstating them, I have traced the problem to one specific type of query that is used in two places. The queries are:

```
select * from zzproductdata
where amazonproductid <> '' and amazoncategory1 ='' and disabled = 0
and productid in (select productid from zzdropshipstock where quantity >= 10)
```

And:

```
select 'ZZ Product Data With Image' as 'Statistic', count(zzproductdataid) as 
'Number' from zzproductdata
where imagescollecteddate <> '0000-00-00' and zzproductdata.productid in 
(select productid from zzdropshipstock where quantity >= 80)
```

Both queries contain a sub-query and both deal with a table called zzproductdata.

A couple things checked: 
1. Other queries containing sub-queries continue to work. 
2. Other queries containing zzproductdata continue to work, as long as they do not contain a sub-query.

When the above two queries run, the CPU gradually increases to 100% over about 90 seconds. It remains at 100% and does not seem to recover - I allowed it to run like this for 3 hours and it did not stop or complete the query.

Table zzproductdata has gradually been collecting data and has increased to 1,500,000 records over the last 12 days. I monitor the amount of time each query takes to run within the database, and these two queries have been gradually getting longer but not excessively so - they have gone from 2.5 seconds to 5.6 seconds.

All of a sudden they have just started going to 100% CPU with no warning. In mysqladmin processlist in terminal I see two records - one showing the process in 'Sleep' status, and one saying 'Sending Data' status.

I suspect that the queries have just hit some kind of sql cache limit, but I cannot work out which cache limit is used by mysql for using sub-queries. I have tried changing some settings in mysql but none of them seem to have an effect. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `zzproductdata` (
 `zzproductdataid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `zzproductdataname` text NOT NULL,
 `disabled` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `datecreated` date NOT NULL,
 `masteronly` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `productid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `isbn` text NOT NULL,
 `ean` text NOT NULL,
 `publishername` text NOT NULL,
 `imagethumbnail` text NOT NULL,
 `imagefull` text NOT NULL,
 `amazonproductid` text NOT NULL,
 `productdatasource` text NOT NULL,
 `datelastupdatedamazon` date NOT NULL,
 `datelastupdatedgoogle` date NOT NULL,
 `googleproductid` text NOT NULL,
 `publicationdate` date NOT NULL,
 `binding` text NOT NULL,
 `imagescollecteddate` date NOT NULL,
 `amazoncategory1` text NOT NULL,
 `amazoncategory2` text NOT NULL,
 `amazoncategory3` text NOT NULL,
 `datelastcheckedamazoncategory` date NOT NULL,
 `datelastupdatedopenlibrary` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`zzproductdataid`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1674296
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf

CREATE TABLE `zzdropshipstock` (
 `zzdropshipstockid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `zzdropshipstockname` text NOT NULL,
 `disabled` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `datecreated` date NOT NULL,
 `masteronly` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `zzdropshipsupplierid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` double NOT NULL,
 `suppliercode` text NOT NULL,
 `supplierprice` double NOT NULL,
 `standardshipcost` double NOT NULL,
 `weightgram` double NOT NULL,
 `rrp` double NOT NULL,
 `productid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `initialimportdate` date NOT NULL,
 `lastupdateddate` date NOT NULL,
 `changed` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `lastcheckedproductiddate` date NOT NULL,
 `lastcheckedproductinamazondate` date NOT NULL,
 `lastcheckedrawstockdata` date NOT NULL,
 `lastcheckedproductstockitemlive` date NOT NULL,
 `changedquantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`zzdropshipstockid`),
 KEY `isbn` (`isbn`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=7037817
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Using EXPLAIN on the first query - I get this: 
[image: Explain image]

This is what I see in Terminal: 
[image: Terminal image]

I have tried adding DISTINCT but it had no effect. It slowed down the escalation of CPU usage, so it took almost 200 seconds to get to 100% CPU usage, but it did not run the query.

The first part of the query returns 1,300,000 records in 0.23 seconds. The subquery returns 118,000 records in 2.3 seconds. This is when you run the two parts separately. Combining the two into one query, should currently return about 15,000 records.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the zzproductdata and zzdropshipstock tables? It would be nice if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE zzproductdata;` output along with explain information for these queries.

Comment: Have you tried adding `DISTINCT` to your subqueries? You could also, after adding DISTINCT, move the subquery into the `FROM` and `INNER JOIN` to it. MySQL does not handle `OR` conditions well (compared to many other conditions) and `IN` is basically an `OR` (though I understand optimizations have been made for `IN` in the latest versions).

Comment: I do not think that DISTINCT helps. For the first query I think the issue is -- too many results ('Sending data'). I think "amazonproductid <> '' and amazoncategory1 ='' and disabled = 0" in WHERE is true for majority of records (1.5M) and there are probably quite a lot of products in subquery. This is why I asked for EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start you can try to add these indexes:

1. `ALTER TABLE zzdropshipstock ADD INDEX IX_zzdropshipstock_key (quantity, productid);`
2. `ALTER TABLE zzproductdata ADD INDEX IX_zzproductdata_productid (productid);`

Then execute `ANALYZE TABLE zzdropshipstock`, `ANALYZE TABLE zzproductdata` and show new EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: There is no index between productid's in each table because it causes other queries to massively slow down in other places. Even without the index between the two productid fields it was running fine in 5.6 secs and then just stopped working on the next run. I am sure you are correct that adding these indexes would fix the specific issue on this query and I may will have to do this, and then change the way other scripts work in relation to these tables. But it is extremely weird that it would be running fine in 5.6 secs and then just stop running and max out the CPU.

Comment: Indexes should not make other queries much slower (inserts/updates might be slower). Right now SQL server have to process 1.5M rows in every table. It's too much. It runs out of RAM and swap started. You cannot fix the issue without indexes. When you used to have less data in your tables it fit in memory so it was quite fast. But not any longer.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately both these tables have 1,000s of inserts happening every hour at the moment, and also 10,000s of edits every hour. By adding these indexes it significantly slows down these inserts. If I understand correctly, my options are to either increase memory on the server, or add the indexes/accept the additional time it takes on inserts.

Comment: Then you have to find another way. You cannot expect that SQL server will 'join' two 1.5M tables without indexes in reasonable time. You can add more RAM, but you will face the same issue in another 2 week time. I do not believe that 1000 inserts/hour & 10000 updates/hour would be massively affected by suggested indexes. Just try to add at least the second suggested index. You can also try to optimize inserts: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how MySQL handle `IN` vs `EXISTS`, but broadly speaking you should preference `EXISTS` over `IN` as the `EXISTS` clause returns true on the first match, whereas `IN` may have to create the full set before it determines if there is a match - this could lead to high memory usage. I'm not sure though in the case of MySQL. I know this problem existed in MSSQL 2005 and possibly 2008, and I wouldn't be surprised if the same problem exists even in modern versions of MySQL, given it's not as polished as some enterprise grade RDMSs.

Spiel over, try this code to see if it improves things:

```
select *
from zzproductdata as pd
where amazonproductid <> ''
and amazoncategory1 =''
and disabled = 0
and exists (
    select *
    from zzdropshipstock as dss
    where quantity >= 10
    and pd.productid = dss.productid
)
```

Comment: A correlated subquery against 1.5 million rows might make things worse. While the IN has to create a full set, it only does so once; the EXISTS has to execute for every relevant outer row, and costs more the less likely it is to find an existing record (elimination is more costly than inclusion).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This did not improve things. It just simply made the CPU get to 100% in 12 seconds instead of 90 seconds. I don't know whether this increase in the speed of getting to max CPU helps identify the problem.

Comment: @Uueerdo "the EXISTS has to execute" --- does it? SQL does not imply that, proper query optimisers would turn it into an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: The EXISTS is not the concern, it is the correlated nature of the query within it that is.

Comment: I agree that correlated sub-queries are harder by its nature. This is why optimizer quite often convert it to join as IN (subquery). Unfortunately, without knowledge about sql version, existing data and statistic available for server it is only guessing.